# How to insert tabs inside drop-down menu in Bootstrap 5?

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

I am using the bootstrap 5 drop-down menus with tabs inside. Here is the code in I found this link useful to stop click event propagation so that the drop-down menu does not close on click inside itAvoid dropdown menu close on click inside.

**I want to put the tabs inside the menu. That I can make something like this later.**

How can I put tabs on my menu?

[image: menu]

I want to make something like this:  https://codepen.io/elhaw/pen/JZjJpJ?editors=1010

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-U1DAWAznBHeqEIlVSCgzq+c9gqGAJn5c/t99JyeKa9xxaYpSvHU5awsuZVVFIhvj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <form>
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                      Dropdown link
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                        <div class="container">
                            <ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a id="tab-A" href="#pane-A" class="nav-link active" data-bs-toggle="tab" role="tab">–A–</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a id="tab-B" href="#pane-B" class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">–B–</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a id="tab-C" href="#pane-C" class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">–C–</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
    
    
                            <div id="content" class="tab-content" role="tablist">
                                <div id="pane-A" class="card tab-pane fade show active" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-A">
                                    <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="heading-A">
                                        <h5 class="mb-0">
                  <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-A" data-parent="#content" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse-A">
                    Collapsible Group Item A
                  </a>
                </h5>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="collapse-A" class="collapse show" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-A">
                                        <div class="card-body">
                                            [Tab content A]
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
    
                                <div id="pane-B" class="card tab-pane fade" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-B">
                                    <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="heading-B">
                                        <h5 class="mb-0">
                  <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-B" data-parent="#content" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-B">
                    Collapsible Group Item B
                  </a>
                </h5>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="collapse-B" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-B">
                                        <div class="card-body">
                                            [Tab content B]
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
    
                                <div id="pane-C" class="card tab-pane fade" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-C">
                                    <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="heading-C">
                                        <h5 class="mb-0">
                  <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-C" data-parent="#content" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-C">
                    Collapsible Group Item C
                  </a>
                </h5>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="collapse-C" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-C">
                                        <div class="card-body">
                                            [Tab content C]
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about your question? What is the problem here?

Comment: @Rüzgar  I updated my post...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How about this?

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-U1DAWAznBHeqEIlVSCgzq+c9gqGAJn5c/t99JyeKa9xxaYpSvHU5awsuZVVFIhvj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown" style="position: initial;">
          <form>
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-bs-auto-close="outside" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Dropdown link
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" style="width: 100%;" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
              <div class="container">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
                  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                    <button class="nav-link active" id="pane-A" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#paneA" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="paneA" aria-selected="true">-A-</button>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                    <button class="nav-link" id="pane-B" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#paneB" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="paneB" aria-selected="false">-B-</button>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                    <button class="nav-link" id="pane-C" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#paneC" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="paneC" aria-selected="false">-C-</button>
                  </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
                  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="paneA" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pane-A">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseA" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseA">
                      Collapsible Group Item A
                    </a>
                    <div class="collapse" id="collapseA">
                      <div class="card card-body">
                        ---- Content A ----
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="paneB" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pane-B">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseB" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseB">
                      Collapsible Group Item B
                    </a>
                    <div class="collapse" id="collapseB">
                      <div class="card card-body">
                        ---- Content B ----
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="paneC" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pane-C">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseC" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseC">
                      Collapsible Group Item C
                    </a>
                    <div class="collapse" id="collapseC">
                      <div class="card card-body">
                        ---- Content C ----
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

> PS: I changed some of the attributes and id's. You can change them as you wish.